# Match first executable path in list in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I was looking for a way to put quotes in Windows Services paths that don't have them because they have spaces. See https://regex101.com/r/N6cbk8/2 for the regex I found which highlights the strings I want to put in quotes, so for example:

```
D:\SerPatHL7Server\RunAsService.exe runasservice d:\SerPatHL7Server\SerPatHL7server.exe
```

needs to become

```
"D:\SerPatHL7Server\RunAsService.exe" runasservice d:\SerPatHL7Server\SerPatHL7server.exe
```

And the other services need also needs quotes like so:

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\Endobase\ebserver.exe
```

to become

```
"E:\Program Files (x86)\Endobase\ebserver.exe"
```

But PowerShell won't accept the \K in `| Select-String -Pattern "(^.*?)\K\.exe"` and throws the error: `"The string (^.\*?)\K\.exe is not a valid regular expression: parsing "(^.*?)\K\.exe" - Unrecognized escape sequence \K."`

I couldn't find an alternative with my limited knowledge of Regex expressions.
See the above link for a full list of examples. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Remove `\K`, you do not need it here. Use `-replace "^.*?\.exe(?!\S)", '"$&"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\K` is a match reset operator used in PCRE, Boost, Python PiPy regex and Onigmo libraries. You do not need this operator in .NET because it supports an infinite width lookbehind (and `\K` is actually a kind of this lookbehind work around).

You just need to match any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first `.exe` that is followed with whitespace or end of string and replace with `"` + match + `"`.

Use

```
-replace "^.*?\.exe(?!\S)", '"$&"'
```

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than newline as few as possible
- `\.` - a literal `.`
- `exe` - a literal `exe` substring
- `(?!\S)` - there should be whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.
- `"$&"` - the replacement pattern where `$&` stands for the whole match.

Comment: Beautiful! It works like a charm. I've added your regex above https://regex101.com/r/N6cbk8/3 and the code example also worked in my script.

Comment: @SuHwak Note that regex101 does not support .NET regex syntax and only treat the demo above as a hint on how it works, but not a proof it works in .NET. E.g., you need to [use `"$0"` as a substitution pattern](https://regex101.com/r/N6cbk8/4) there.