# Powershell - Get the third directory of a path with Regex

Tags: regex, string, path

With the `git log` command, I get all changes from a commit and I store it in a file.

This is de result:

```
microsoft/netframework/docker/content/Y
```

I want to get **only** the **third folder**, `docker`.

I tried with these regex expression: `'/[\/]*[^\/]+[\/]([^\/]+)/'`

But it returns:

```
microsoftcontent/Y
```

What should I correct in the expression to **use with Powershell**?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using? It affects what possible solutions there are.

Comment: I updated it, I use powershell

Comment: Answering that became too awkward, because now you've invalidated a perfectly fine answer by GillesQuenot. However, [this here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%5c%2f%29%7b2%7d%28%5cw%2b%29&i=microsoft%2fnetframework%2fdocker%2fcontent%2fY) should work in powershell.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It returns `microsoft/netframework/docker` not only `docker` folder.

Comment: Try `$s -replace '^(?:[^/]*/){2}([^/]+).*', '$1'` (Powershell). Or try a matching pattern - `(?<=^(?:[^/]*/){2})[^/]+`

Comment: @SteveMason it matches "docker" as the first matching group. Are you in a situation where you don't even have access to "$1"?

Comment: @SteveMason I updated the answer with patterns for both matching and replacing. Since powershell [doesn't seem to support \K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611602/what-is-the-equivalent-to-k-for-regex-in-powershell), it doesn't seem to be possible to do it without replacement.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you can easily [handle it without any replacement](https://imgur.com/a/QaZ2V), see `$matches[0]`. Actually, you may use capturing that OP is so afraid of and access it via `$matches[1]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know anything about powershell. But every not-self-written regex engine that I've encountered so far allowed to access the matched groups in one way or the other. If this is how it can be done in powershell: good, I believe it. In this case the OP is "not in a situation where [he doesn't] even have access to $1". If accessing matched groups is so simple, then I don't know what the problem with my first solution was. The online regex-testing utility provided both a table of matched groups *and* an input field for replacement. Now my example contains both possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in `powershell`, you should have the possibility to select single groups of the matched pattern.

[This regex in combination with replacement pattern](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%5c%2f%29%7b2%7d%28%5cw%2b%29%28%5c%2f.*%29&i=microsoft%2fnetframework%2fdocker%2fcontent%2fY&r=%241) matches the entire string, but retains only `docker` after replacement (click on "Context" tab).

Regex:

```
^(?:\w+\/){2}(\w+)(\/.*)
```

Replacement:

```
$1
```

The first group isn't matched because of `:?`. The last group is simply not used in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Check online https://regex101.com/r/8ELSUx/2

```
^(?:\w+\/){2}\K\w+
```

You have all explanations on the right panel

Comment: That regular expression is not valid with Powershell. I'm sorry I did not add that point. I just updated the post.